# PostgreSQL how to convert date with timezone offset to UTC?

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table with date field in the following format

`2017-09-07T17:24:33+08:00`

and I want to convert it to UTC time.

I've looked around but found no way to do that with this specific time format. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a PostgreSQL table with date field in the following format: `2017-09-07T17:24:33+08:00`

This is incorrect. Per [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES),

> All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They are converted to local time in the zone specified by the TimeZone configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.

To display a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` attribute (which, again, is stored internally in UTC) in a specific time zone, you have a few options:

- By default, “They are converted to local time in the zone specified by the **TimeZone** configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.” This can be set in `postgresql.conf`, using the SQL command `SET TIME ZONE`, or using a number of other options.
- Use the `AT TIME ZONE` [construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT).

So, in regards to your original question: You don't have to do anything to your `timestamptz` for Postgres to store it in UTC. To *display* your attribute in UTC, you can either change the `TimeZone` configuration paramter, or use the construct below:

```
SELECT dt_with_timezone AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 5):

`timezone` definition (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html) : The function timezone(**zone**, **timestamp**) is equivalent to the SQL-conforming construct **timestamp** AT TIME ZONE **zone**

```
SELECT timezone('UTC','2017-09-07T17:24:33+08:00');
```

if selecting from column,

```
with t as (
    SELECT '2017-09-07T17:24:33+08:00' as tm
)
SELECT timezone('UTC',tm::timestamptz) as ts
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as you wrote it but it does not work when I use a table column instead of the hardcoded timestamp (eg. `SELECT timezone('UTC', time_column)`). I'm getting the error `SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function timezone(unknown, text) does not exist. Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`. 
Should I cast the column to timestamp? If you have any suggestion can you update your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @crash function expects timestamp datatype, so casting should work, see updated answer

Comment: If it's at all possible change the column definition from "text" to "timestamp with time zone". If you leave it as text you can count on having issues at some point. Always store date containing data as a date defining data_type.